# jQuery Mobile Conference example

Tags: jquery-mobile

Awhile back when I first read about jQuery mobile I remember seeing an example site that was written for some tech conference. It had Google maps integration and a schedule. I think it was for an O'Reilly (the publisher) conference. Does anyone know where I might find a link to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the [jQuery Mobile Gallery](http://www.jqmgallery.com), there are 13 pages of jQM sites, you might be able to find the one you are looking for, or something else similar.